# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, TypeError: Failed to fetch at HTMLDocument.requestItems (script.js:56:5)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to use fetch API to get information about my database but I keep getting "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
TypeError: Failed to fetch
at HTMLDocument.requestItems (script.js:56:5)" error

Here's my db.php code to connect to database

```
    $conn=new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "", "online_canteen_system");
    if($conn->connect_errno){
        echo json_encode(['error'=>$conn->connect_error]);
        exit();
    }
```

and here's my items.php code

```
 <?php 
require 'db.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==="GET"){
    $stmt = "select name from items where status=1;";
    if($result= $_conn->query($stmt)){
        $arr= array();
        while($name= $result->fetch_assoc()['name']){
            array_push($arr,$name); 
        }
        echo json_encode(['items'=>$arr]);
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(['error'=>'an error occured']);
    }
    exit();
}
```

here is the js code for the fetch api

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', requestItems);
function requestItems() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/backend/items.php")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }
        )
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PVaU.png)

Comment: This is not generic JavaScript, but (I think) react. It is useful to indicate which technology you use, so people can give better support.
Anyway, this indicates that the network request failed. Try to check in your browser developer tool in network tab. Maybe you have a 403 or an error in the response content.

Comment: @RobertoBraga — There is absolutely nothing React related there. Everything in the JS section is either from the ECMAScript specification or the standard Web APIs supplied by browsers

Comment: @RobertoBraga — It is not a 403 error. The connection was refused.

Comment: Then @Quentin probably is right

Answer (score 1):

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means that you are not running an HTTP server on port `8080` or `localhost`.

Maybe you got the port number wrong or forgot to start the server.